# Excel Userform (VBA) - How to add value in Total if checkbox is checked

Tags: vba, checkbox, userform, excel-2016

I have multiple checkboxes (1 to 8) in Userform (VBA) and their values are mentioned in Ride.Caption (1 to 8). If I check any checkbox, then its value mentioned in Ride should add in Total Value and If I uncheck any checkbox then the value should deduct from the Total Value

As per the below code, I have added all values in Total. But, Checkbox coding is still pending, and I do not know how I can make this code complete. Help me out with your expertise.

```
Private Sub TotalValue_Click()
Dim X As Double
X = 0
If Len(Ride1.Caption) > 0 Then X = X + Ride1.Caption
If Len(Ride2.Caption) > 0 Then X = X + Ride2.Caption
If Len(Ride3.Caption) > 0 Then X = X + Ride3.Caption
If Len(Ride4.Caption) > 0 Then X = X + Ride4.Caption
If Len(Ride5.Caption) > 0 Then X = X + Ride5.Caption
If Len(Ride6.Caption) > 0 Then X = X + Ride6.Caption
If Len(Ride7.Caption) > 0 Then X = X + Ride7.Caption
If Len(Ride8.Caption) > 0 Then X = X + Ride8.Caption
TotalValue.Caption = X
End Sub
```

https://ibb.co/7jh7mJh

Comment: Well you need to be checking if the checkbox value = true. You could add that as an `and` in your if statements or replace your length checks with checking the checkbox. You actually only need `If Checkbox1 Then ...`

Comment: could you please correct my coding and write it here so that I can easily understand this

Comment: I am just curious as to why are you checking for `Len(Ride1.Caption) > 0`

Comment: Dear I do no know much about coding. I just used it and its working if there is any other method please share

Comment: I have uploaded a screenshot of my work to better understand. This will give you clear idea of coding what will work here

Comment: @DaljeetSingh I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I check any checkbox, then its value mentioned in Ride should add in Total Value and If I uncheck any checkbox then the value should deduct from the Total Value

You can handle all your checkboxes in a loop. Also you do not need to deduct. Simply recalculate.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim TotalSum As Double
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 1 To 8
        If Controls("Ride" & i).Value = True Then
            TotalSum = TotalSum + Val(Controls("CheckBox" & i).Caption)
        End If
    Next i
    
    TotalValue.Caption = TotalSum
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying?
I've done it in a loop as it's cleaner and easier to handle.

You need to change "CheckBox" to whatever your checkboxes are called.

```
Private Sub TotalValue_Click()

Dim X As Double, i As Integer

X = 0
For i = 1 To 8
    If Me.Controls("CheckBox" & i).Value = True  And Len(Me.Controls("Ride" & i).Caption) > 0 Then 
        X = X + Me.Controls("Ride" & i).Caption
    End If
Next i
TotalValue.Caption = X

End Sub
```

Alternatively, if you want your total to update whenever someone checks/unchecks a checkbox then you can add a change event for each of your textboxes like so:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Change()

If Me.CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    Me.TotalValue.Caption = Me.TotalValue.Caption + Val(Me.Ride1.Caption)
Else
    Me.TotalValue.Caption = Me.TotalValue.Caption - Val(Me.Ride1.Caption)
End If

End Sub
```

Again, just change "CheckBox1" to the relevant checkbox name.

Comment: Thank You. Finally, It's working now.
I have one more issue. I am using this Userform multiple times in different worksheets Excel. But, If I select Checkbox in First Userform then other Userform automatically select the same checkbox. How can I separate them? 
I want to choose a checkbox in every Userform as per the requirement. is it possible? or I need to create several Userform with the same content

Comment: Do you mean several workbooks? Im not too sure exactly what your issue is here. I cant say I’ve had it before. Aside from maybe trying to explicitly state the workbook name and userform name instead of using `Me`. Otherwise I’m not too sure without more info.

Comment: I have done this coding. Thank you for the concern